# JsonMappingException handling and deserialize all that we can

Tags: java, jackson-databind

Have a situation when partner API does not work well yet.
The object I receive is something like this

```
{
    "id": 1,         // Can deserealize
    "type": "HUMAN", // Can deserealize
    "age": 18,       // Can deserealize
    "armor": {},     // JsonMappingException
    "weapon": {}     // Can deserealize
}
```

The required solution is to log JsonMappingException and save it in DB, and not crash the object but in result put **null** values instead objects that can not be deserialized.

```
{
    "id": 1,          // Can deserealize
    "type": "HUMAN",  // Can deserealize
    "age": 18,        // Can deserealize
    "armor": null,    // Replaced to null or default object
    "weapon": {}      // Can deserealize
}
```

I have tried to add DeserializationProblemHandler- no method was fired and DeserializationFeature - no feature like I need seems to be present.

How can I specialize the behavior of Jackson so that I can apply this behavour to any object, so if any of fields can not be mapped, I could handle this and replace with null or any default object?

Comment: Could you share the deserialization code?

Comment: `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Player player = null;
try {
 player = mapper.readValue(new File("bad_json.txt"), Player.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
 log.error("Bad json",e);
}` Some classes have deserialiser where I throw JsonMappingException also.

Comment: Could you add it into the question? Also, could you add the structure of `Player` class as well?

Comment: The structure of Player and deserialiser are not important, because I want to handle all Exceptions like this, not only for player. I can handle Exception in Player deserializer but this is not the solution.

Comment: In that case, it should be handled in `Service/Business layer rather than specializing the behavior of Jackson.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a Business use case than `Jackson` specific behavior. Also, in Java, you can't have a method thowing an `Exception` and returning a `value` at the same time.

Instead of writing a custom deserializer (which is completely unnecessary), you can check that field after deserializing and log an error if it's null, before persisting the object, e.g.:

```
String json = ""; //json string
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person person = mapper.readValue(json, Person.class);
if(person.getArmour() == null) {
    LOGGER.error("Received a Person object witn no armour : {}", person.getId());
}
//Save Person object
```

P.S. Above example uses `slf4j`.

Comment: The thing is that I can not get a Person object because `mapper.readValue(json, Person.class);` throws JsonMappingException when deserialize armor object.

Comment: Could you add `Person` class structure and/or deserialization logic? Don't think it should throw `JsonMappingException` if `armour` is null.

Comment: If you look at the question, I have marked that armor throws JsonMappingException. And I wish to catch it, log, and replace armor with null.